# Use host's onboard/integrated graphics from a virtual machine

Tags: linux, vga, kvm-switch, integrated-graphics, qemu

Is there a way to let a VM access/use a monitor connected to the motherboard's VGA port as if it were its own monitor with KVM-QEMU?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=37D2bRsthfI). This answers your question with "yes, it is possible".

I am also interested in passing through my on-board GPU to a virtual machine. But I am not sure if my system fulfill the recommendation:

> "Please note that you'll need both a VT-d capable CPU and mainboard(or
>   the AMD equivalent). And of course, 2 gpus, for example 1 dedicated
>   PCIe card the onboard gpu of a core i* processor."

My system is currently using a single GPU over PCIe. The on-board GPU is shadowed in some way and not visible anymore. Until now I didn't find a way to access it, while the PCIe-card is plugged in.